# Why DataGridView cell does not accept value from textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, oledb

I populate DataGridView1 by typing into cells or by passing text to a cell from TextBox1 when clicking on a button:

*ButtonClick_PassTextToDataGridView1*:

```
 DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

*ButtonClick2_Update DataGridView:*

```
 Dim cmdbuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(adp)        
 adp.Update(ds, "Table1")
```

What I type in the cells are saved into the table, but problem is what I pass from TextBox1.Text to DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2) does not persist.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Before line `adp.Update(ds, "Table1")` check what value in the same row/cell in your datatable

Comment: Consider editing the data directly on the data source and not through a GUI element. Most data structures or containers offer methods like `BeginEdit` or `EndEdit` to mark data explicitly as edited. You can find those methods for example on `DataRow` or `BindingSource`.